# How to set dataSource in quartz schedular. [ERROR] org.quartz.SchedulerException: Could not initialize DataSource: myDS

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-data-jpa, quartz-scheduler

This is my config file quartz.properties

```
org.quartz.scheduler.instanceName= LivingOrdering
org.quartz.scheduler.instanceId=99199
org.quartz.scheduler.rmi.export=false
org.quartz.scheduler.rmi.proxy=false
org.quartz.threadPool.class=org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool
org.quartz.threadPool.threadCount=3
org.quartz.context.key.QuartzTopic=QuartzPorperties
org.quartz.jobStore.class=org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreTX
org.quartz.jobStore.driverDelegateClass=org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.StdJDBCDelegate
org.quartz.jobStore.tablePrefix=qrtz_
org.quartz.jobStore.dataSource=quartzDataSource
org.quartz.dataSource.quartzDataSource.driver=org.postgresql.Driver
org.quartz.dataSource.quartzDataSource.URL=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/quartz
org.quartz.dataSource.quartzDataSource.user=admin
org.quartz.dataSource.quartzDataSource.password=admin
org.quartz.dataSource.quartzDataSource.maxConnections=300
```

I am getting error at the line -:

```java
Scheduler scheduler = new StdSchedulerFactory().getScheduler();
```

```
Error: org.quartz.SchedulerException: Could not initialize DataSource: quartzDataSource
```

Answer (score 4):

I know the question is old, but since I ended up here looking for a solution, and that it wasn't clear what to do, I will provide my solution for the others still looking for one.

**Project config:**

```
JDK: 18.0.1  
Maven: 3.6.3    
Spring boot: 2.7.4  
Quartz: spring-boot-starter-quartz
```

The below config works if you want to have a single datasource for your app and quartz.

I use it for tests for example.

```
spring:
  datasource:
    url: jdbc:h2:mem:db;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1
    driverClassName: org.h2.Driver
    username: sa
    password: sa
  quartz:
    job-store-type: jdbc
    jdbc:
      initialize-schema: never
    properties:
      org:
        quartz:
          jobStore:
            class: org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.LocalDataSourceJobStore
            driverDelegateClass: org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.PostgreSQLDelegate
            tablePrefix: TB_PR_QRTZ_
```

Also don't forget to tag your datasource bean with `@QuartzDatasource`.

```
@Primary
@Bean
@QuartzDataSource
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.datasource")
public DataSource defaultDatasource (){
    return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
}
```

But if you need 2 datasources, you have to specify a custom datasource in spring.quartz.properties.org.quartz.dataSource.

Here is my config for the app:

```
spring:
  datasource:
    byq:
      url: jdbc:oracle:thin:@//app-db/schema-name
      driverClassName: oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
      username: ZZZ
      password: XXX
  quartz:
    job-store-type: jdbc
    wait-for-jobs-to-complete-on-shutdown: true
    jdbc:
      initialize-schema: never
    properties:
      org:
        quartz:
          dataSource:
            quartzDataSource:
              URL: jdbc:postgresql://scheduler-db/scheduler
              driver: org.postgresql.Driver
              user: ZZZ
              password: XXX
          jobStore:
            dataSource: quartzDataSource
            class: org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreTX
            driverDelegateClass: org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.PostgreSQLDelegate
            tablePrefix: TB_QRTZ_
```

Answer (score 2):

SpringBoot has Quartz auto configuration, you don't need to configure Quartz using quartz.properties as it knows nothing about Spring so you cannot just put a datasource name in there. Read [the documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-quartz.html#boot-features-quartz).

All you need to get started with Quartz is to include the starter in you pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-quartz</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Configure your standard Spring datasource (application.properties):

```
spring.datasource.url = jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/quartz
spring.datasource.username = admin
spring.datasource.password = admin
```

Then add (in application.properties):

```
spring.quartz.job-store-type=jdbc
# Add the below line to have Spring Boot auto create the Quartz tables
spring.quartz.jdbc.initialize-schema=always
```

If you want to pass additional properties to Quartz you can prefix the property name with `spring.quartz.properties` like so:

```
spring.quartz.properties.org.quartz.scheduler.instanceName=LivingOrdering
```

Comment: can you have a look on my question maybe you can help

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68710946/is-spring-boot-starter-quartz-offer-auto-configuration-or-i-missing-something-n

Comment: this will not work with the latest spring 2.6.2 and quartz 2.3.2 which will be loaded with `org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-quartz`. The exception: `Caused by: org.quartz.SchedulerConfigException: DataSource name not set.` quartz needs separate datasource config with the latest realase ofspring.

Comment: Looks like from from 2.5.7 there are changes https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/28846 in required configuration properties. In my case I added `org.quartz.dataSource.NAME.(driver, URL, user, password, provider)` and `spring.quartz.properties.org.quartz.jobStore.dataSource=NAME`. Important information that you can miss `spring.quartz.properties.org.quartz.jobStore` section or write `job-store` instead of `jobStore` and program can even run without `dataSource` information as well using your application DB but you quartz settings doesn't work at all in this case.

Comment: Quartz datasource configuration settings documentation http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.3.0/configuration/ConfigDataSources.html

Answer (score 0):

As a note here, in the `quartz.properties` file, the properties names start with `org.quartz...` ; with the later versions of quartz (after 2.5.6 if I'm not wrong) they start with `spring.quartz.properties.org.quartz...` .

Just had this issue when I've updated the SpringBoot version from 2.1.2 to 2.6.3 (including quartz libraries) and the error was the same as in this post question.

Answer (score -1):

get rid of spring.datasource.* from application.properties file and , add `spring.datasource.name= quartzDataSource`  works for me.

- you may have to configure your `org.quartz.dataSource.quartzDataSource.provider` as well (hikaricp or c3po-default)